# Referencing global variables that are passed in using argv[]

Tags: c, argv

I have some global variables of type int defined, and I want them to be matched with command line arguments to avoid endless chains of `if` statements with `strcmp`. For example, if I have defined the global variable `myvar`, and the user types `myvar` as a command line argument, I want to be able to reference `myvar` and perform operations on it using `argv[]`. Can this be done?

Editing my question just to make it a little more clear:

Currently, I'm having to do this:

```
int* A;
int* B;
int* C;

int set(void)
{
    if (strcmp((gargv[2]), "A") == 0)
    {
        *A = atoi(gargv[3]);
        return *A;
    }

    else if (strcmp((gargv[2]), "B") == 0)
    {
        *B = atoi(gargv[3]);
        return *B;
    }

    else if (strcmp((gargv[2]), "C") == 0)
    {
        *C = atoi(gargv[3]);
        return *C;
    }
    else 
    {
        errx(EX_USAGE, "Invalid");
    }
}


int main (int argc, char** argv) 
{
    gargv = argv;

    void* mem_chunk = calloc(5, sizeof(int));

    A = &mem_chunk[1];
    B = &mem_chunk[2];
    C = &mem_chunk[3];

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "set") == 0)
    {
        set();
    }
}
```

But it would be way less cumbersome to just do something like this, where I can set `argv[2]` to `argv[3]`, referencing the global variables A, B, or C:

```
int* A;
int* B;
int* C;

int set(void)
{
    gargv[2] = gargv[3];
    // example, if A and 10 given by user then set A = 10 and return
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) 
{
    gargv = argv;

    void* mem_chunk = calloc(5, sizeof(int));

    A = &mem_chunk[1];
    B = &mem_chunk[2];
    C = &mem_chunk[3];

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "set") == 0)
    {
        set();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, use a strcmp chain

Comment: Or use `getopt` and pass the needed arguments and values as required. The matching globals seems like a hit-or-miss approach, but I'm not entirely clear on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague. Of course you can set a global variable based on the command line arguments passed, you do that by first examining/parsing `argv` setting all your configuration variables.

This is in fact the typical structure of a command line program, the arguments are parsed first and later in the program, you only use configuration values and flags that were set during parsing.

It's not entirely clear, but I assume you also look for tools to simplify parsing command line arguments. Well, there are many. On *nix systems, there's typically [`getopt()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) in the standard library (it's specified in POSIX). Note this manpage also describes `getopt_long()`, a GNU extension only available with GNUs C library (`glibc`).

If `getopt()` is to simple for what you need or you want to use it on systems like windows, have a look at an old and well-known library for command line parsing: [`popt`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/popt). You will probably find `popt` implementations for nearly any system with google.

Then there's always the possibility to *once* write your own and reuse it yourself. I have [my own](https://github.com/Zirias/pocas/blob/master/src/lib/core/cmdline.c) because I needed a command line interface that's statefully parsed, like a scripting language -- just to give you an idea.

---

Your question gives me the idea that with a commandline like that:

```
> yourprogram foo=nanana bar=frobnicate
```

you would like to set the variables `foo` and `bar` in your program. This is not the *typical* command line interface using switches with optional arguments and positional arguments, so `getopt()` will not give you exactly that. But it's quite easy to write a parser for that, as this little demo shows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// configuration for the parser:
struct argvVar
{
    const char *name;    // the name of the variable to look for
    const char **value;  // the address of the variable to set the value
};

void parseArgvVars(int argc, char **argv, const struct argvVar *vars)
{
    // loop over argv:
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        // loop over configuration items:
        const struct argvVar *var = vars;
        while (var->name)
        {
            // compare variable name with current argument:
            const char *vname = var->name;
            const char *arg = argv[i];
            while (*arg && *vname)
            {
                // when different, try the next configured variable:
                if (*arg != *vname) goto nextVar;
                ++arg;
                ++vname;
            }
            if (*arg == '=')
            {
                // when matching and the following sign is an equals sign,
                // assign to the variable:
                *var->value = arg + 1;
            }
nextVar:
            ++var;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *foo = 0;
    const char *bar = 0;
    const char *baz = 0;

    // list of variables we want to assign from argv values:
    const struct argvVar vars[] = {
        {"foo", &foo},
        {"bar", &bar},
        {"baz", &baz},
        {0, 0} // end of list
    };

    parseArgvVars(argc, argv, vars);

    if (foo) printf("foo: %s\n", foo);
    if (bar) printf("bar: %s\n", bar);
    if (baz) printf("baz: %s\n", baz);

    return 0;
}
```

Try to understand the usage of a configuration structure and the generic nature of the parsing function, so you can learn how to solve a problem once and reuse the code often.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use getopt() or strncmp().
Example:

```
strncmp(argv[index], your_string, dim);
```